# Spring Boot java with groovy , How to compile together into an executable jar

Tags: maven, spring-boot, groovy

I use groovy as the controller, I using the idea of running can compile groovy to .class, but

> MVN clean package

won't compile the groovy files

Comment: You should at least provide the minimal failing example (e.g. the pom.xml).

Comment: Do you mean to say both `.java` and `.groovy` source files used in the project?